# Eclipse settings affect Maven command-line build?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

Most of our projects are built with Maven, and some of them use classes in the com.sun package. That's a bad practice, but there's not much I can do about it.

For a while this didn't seem to be a big problem. Then, at some point, builds started failing for me with errors such as the following:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        Access restriction: The type TextSerializer is not accessible due to res
triction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_15\lib\rt.jar
```

That's fair enough, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to turn off that check. The builds were failing both from the command line and from within Eclipse, so I assumed it must be some Maven setting.

Eventually I figured out that the problem was somehow with **Eclipse**. I went to Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Deprecated and restricted API and changed 'Forbidden Reference' to 'Warning'. Thereafter, my builds started working. This is completely incomprehensible to me, because I was getting the errors when building **from the command line**.

Can someone please explain to me how an **Eclipse** setting can somehow affect the behaviour of a build from the command line?!

Comment: Is Eclipse set to use the same JRE as Maven?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is set to use the same JRE.

Comment: and if you restore the Eclipse preference your build starts failing again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You faced the [Compilation errors on restricted classes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+FAQ#ProjectFAQ-Compilationerrorsonrestrictedclasses) issue mentioned in the m2eclipse FAQ and applied the same solution as suggested in the FAQ:

> Projects using classes from `rt.jar`,
>   such as `com.sun.*` (and some others)
>   can have compilation errors like:
>   "Access restriction: The type RE is
>   not accessible due to restriction on
>   required library
>   /lib/rt.jar". Such errors
>   indicate use of non-API classes and
>   those access rules are defined by
>   Eclipse JDT.
>
> You can change compiler settings to
>   not fail on those restrictions in
>   workspace settings in Window /
>   Preferences / Java / Compiler /
>   Errors/Warnings / Deprecated and
>   restricted API / Forbidden reference
>   (access rules) / Warnings; or
>   per-project from Project / Properties
>   / Java Compiler / Errors/Warnings
>   / Deprecated and restricted API /
>   Forbidden reference (access rules) /
>   Warnings

<strike>This should of course not affect a JDK outside Eclipse. Having that said, you wrote in a comment that Eclipse is set to use the same JRE as Maven but... Maven needs a JDK to compile classes (it needs javac). So my guess is that you're actually using a non-javac compiler and have a [compilerId](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html) declared somewhere. Something like this:</strike>

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
      <version>xxxx</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This tells the compiler-plugin to use the eclipse compiler and, somehow, its settings.

**EDIT:** As per comment, the hypothesis mentioned above doesn't apply for the OP.

My next suggestion was to try reproducing the problem but to run `mvn clean` before `compile` e.g.:

```
mvn clean install
```

As reported, it appears that this solves the issue (as I was expecting). I should have thought bout this immediately: Eclipse produces .class files even for classes with compilation errors. Hence the (not so) weird behavior at the maven command line level solved by a `clean`.

Actually, my advice would be to use the settings mentioned in [How to configure Maven project to use separate output folders in Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+FAQ#ProjectFAQ-HowtoconfigureMavenprojecttouseseparateoutputfoldersinEclipse) to avoid any similar problem. This was actually the default of m2eclipse prior to version 0.9.4. The reasons of this change are discussed in [this dev-list thread](http://markmail.org/message/733lqtw5moa4cim4).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I grepped the whole project for "compilerId" and it showed up nothing, so that isn't it.

Comment: Is maven really using the same JRE as Eclipse? What's the value of JAVA_HOME?

Comment: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15
PATH includes %JAVA_HOME%\bin
Eclipse is set to use the same version.
The choice of Java 1.5.0_15 is deliberate due to a project here that 'requires' it, but I tried with 1.6.0_16 and got the same problem.

Comment: Ok, so maven is actually using a JDK... Another question: can you reproduce the problem? If yes, what does happen if you run `mvn clean` before to compile?

Comment: I have reliably reproduced the problem on two different machines -- otherwise I would have concluded that I was going mad. I had thought I’d tried mvn clean, but apparently not. My colleague beat you to the suggestion by a few minutes, and trying it solved the problem and led me to the explanation -- see my answer above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have now that you've changed the answer :). I will change the Eclipse target folder as you suggest, which should damn well be the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very nice from you (notice I used a smiley). Regarding the output folders, I agree with you and dislike when eclipse and maven use the same output folders. I find there are more disadvantages than advantages to use collocated folders.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's helpful to give Eclipse builds a separate directory from Maven CLI builds:

Insert the following into your pom.xml. The existence of the "m2e.version" property will activate the following profile which alters the location of the Eclipse build

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>IDE</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>m2e.version</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <!-- Put the IDE's build output in a folder other than target, so that IDE builds don't interact with Maven builds -->
      <directory>target-ide</directory>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: This works for basic scenarios, and is what _should_ be all that's required, but may be better (i.e. work around various Eclipse m2e integrations) if combined with the info we found at http://wayback.archive.org/web/20081014090406/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+FAQ#ProjectFAQ-HowtoconfigureMavenprojecttouseseparateoutputfoldersinEclipse, which lacks your good use of <activation>

Answer (score 0):

My colleague helpfully pointed out that `mvn clean install` fixes the problem. Eventually we worked out that (M2)Eclipse is leaving some partially compiled classes in the target directory, and of course vanilla Maven doesn’t know that it should recompile those classes. I’m a little bit annoyed about this. It should be obvious to anyone that leaving broken output in the target directory is bound to subtly pollute later builds.

Comment: See my answer for a solution to the problem you mention.

Comment: FWIW, you should not have different headless and IDE compiler settings. Your question shows exactly why.

Comment: The setting in question doesn't even *exist* in the vanilla compiler. So, while your suggestion is reasonable, it presupposes that one is aware of every obscure feature in the Eclipse compiler and how to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

yeah the "clean" is the key
Note however that it's not just that it has failure builds around--somehow or other m2eclipse just leaves junk behind, even if it compiles right.

This can also cause things like

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

from the command line

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing similar issues using Netbeans (6.9.1) with a Maven project. `mvn clean` resolves the problem.